# Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log' when running Selenium tests on Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am trying to run selenium tests on firefox 48. I am getting following error.

```
if log_path:
    log_file = open(log_path, "a+")
    IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'

C:\Users\ABC\getTalent\venv\getTalent\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\service.py:45: IOError
```

Same code is running fine on Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Gekodriver should first be added in path,then set the path of the driver on script for firefox.

```
    firefox_dir = "/usr/local/selenium/webdriver/firefox"
    ff_profile = selenium.webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile_directory=firefox_dir)
    driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(ff_profile)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add file,geckodirver.exe to the PATH